# Bundle Version String error (again)

Tags: ios, xcode, cfbundleidentifier

I am having an issue uploading an api file.  I have a client, so I am just the developer and do not have access to their iTunes connect.  Given they are a client, I would like to stop being a pain in their a@#.   I have tried to upload and continue to get that the CFBunderVersion must be a higher number than previous.

I looked at the binary details, and they are as follows:

```
 Bundle Short String:  2
 Bundle Version:  80
```

We are on version 2.1.81.   When I first tried to upload the file, it gave me errors that the Bundles needed to be integers.   So, I got lost in the land of version and entered 2 for short, and 80 for bundle.

I am trying to put in an update.  I have tried 3 and 81, 2 and 81, 2 and 1.81, 2.0 and 81.0...and continue to get the same error.

Any suggestions on how I can get this resolved, get into my real version numbers and actually update the app in iTunes connect?

Answer (score 2):

The bundle integer for 2.1.81 is 20181. It's your version number + your 2-digit major revision number + your 2-digit minor revision number.

You also have the ability to retrieve the bundle as a float in your code, if you like:

```
[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] floatValue]
```